# What is the usage of these "would"?

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider:

> The story begins with narration explaining that only exceptional humans become aware of the Matrix on their own (without help from redpill hackers). This **would** be people who have "a rare degree of intuition, sensitivity, and a questioning nature." However, "some attain this wisdom through wholly different means." [Source1](http://www.matrixresolutions.com/index.html?page=animatrix6_world_record)
>
> Both the Merovingian and Oracle use Matrix humans to process all information that is flowing through the Matrix at any given time. It **would** only make sense for the Oracle to take over trafficking of information since doing so is not anywhere near as intense of a duty as what she's already doing with all the information, namely calculating the future.
>
> I think the Merovingian knows why the One needs to return to the Source since the Merovingian monitors all information in the Matrix - this information **would** have to include the Prime Program's encapsulation of rejection into the One.
> [Source2](http://www.matrixresolutions.com/index.html?page=merovingian_eyes_of_the_oracle)

I cannot find out the implicit hypothetical conditions in these examples.

Please help me to clarify what these bolded **would** is intended to express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All OP's examples do in fact include some element of a "hypothetical situation".

In #1, it's ***if we were attempting to identify*** exactly what kind of people *"become aware of the Matrix on their own"*, this is what we ***would*** find. This indirect/weakening effect of *would* for hypothetical *if I had to say something* has been covered by a previous question about [*"That would be correct"*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18346/what-does-this-would-mean).

In the same vein, #2 implies ***if we were trying to "rationalise"*** how and why the Merovingian and Oracle use Matrix humans, and #3 implies ***if we were to examine all Merovingian-monitored information***.

---

In all these examples (and particularly the *"That would be correct"* link), it's almost meaningless to say the "hypothetical" scenario is any different to *reality*. Effectively, it's just a stylistic device which may or may not have slight implications for the meaning.

Comment: I would think these _would + verb_ can be reasonably substituted by simple present form of the main verb, right?

Comment: @Zhanlong Zheng: [That would be right](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18346/what-does-this-would-mean#comment33692_18347), yes.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when expressing a conjecture, opinion, or hope, we use "would" this way.

**Example -**

> 1. I would imagine that they’re home by now.
> 2. I guess some people would consider it brutal
> 3. I would have to agree

I think in your sentence it's expressing an opinion. So the verb "have to" takes "would", here.

Comment: Yes, good answer. When you hit an example like this, see if inserting "in my opinion" after "would" makes sense.

Comment: I got it. Even Neo says himself in the movie, " If I had to guess, I'd say you're a program from the machine world. So is he."